# Positioning components in Ext JS

Tags: button, extjs, components, panel

Here's what I have:

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

Here's some code:

```
                        { xtype: 'combobox', padding: 5, fieldLabel: 'Search In', store: states, displayField: 'field1', id: 'criteria_3_drop_down', hidden: true  },
                        { xtype: 'textfield', padding: 5, region: 'west', fieldLabel: 'Criteria 3', id: 'criteria_3_input', hidden: true   },
                        { xtype: 'button', text: 'Search', margin: '0 0 5 120', padding: '0 30 0 30', itemId: 'search'},
                        { xtype: 'button', text: '+', id: 'add_criteria' }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post more information and any attempts you have already made

Comment: I put some code in that I currently have

Comment: @user2291971 I hope we won't be seeing any further outbursts like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `FieldContainer` to group the criteria box and the + button together with an `hbox`:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    fieldLabel: 'Criteria 3',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'textfield', id: 'criteria_3_input' },
        { xtype: 'button', text: '+', id: 'add_criteria' }
    ]
}
```